# ajax cross domain error on SAME domain?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Client of mine has a wordpress blog that we are ajaxing the rss feed to the homepage to display the past 3 posts... I'm using jquery and all was working perfect.

We changed our IP to a dedicated IP and all of a sudden it stopped working. my XHR is 0! I'm assuming it thinks it's a cross domain issue.

For a temp fix I wrote a php proxy to load the file and I'm ajaxing that -- (which works - note: file is in the wp dir so it's not a dir wide issue)

thanks!

//EDIT (CODE)

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/blog/?feed=rss2',
     success: function() {
       alert('worked');
     },
    error: function(x){
        alert(x.status);
    }
});

$.ajax({
     url: '/blog/proxy.php',
     success: function() {
       alert('worked');
     },
    error: function(x){
        alert(x.status);
    }
});
```

Note: proxy.php just fopens "/blog/?feed=rss2"

I'm successful on proxy.php but getting jqXHR.status = 0

Comment: What makes you to believe that it was not cross-domain issue?

Comment: typically when you get a xhr it's because your trying to access cross domain or because the file is unavailable. well, the file is def available - but i'm still getting the status=0. permissions are messed up somewhere and i think i just don't have access now to ajax it

Comment: Can you provide some code for this?

Comment: Have you tried accessing /blog/proxy.php in your browser? Do you get a response then? If you get a response, you're probably right about the cross domain issues, but I think it might just as well be a problem with fopen over network connections.

Comment: yeah, I can load proxy.php no problem - and it renders the xml perfect... Also when ajaxing the proxy it works as well. Just doesn't work when trying to ajax the file directly. Note: it USED to work until we switched IP addresses

Comment: Could it be something related to datatype? It doesn't explain how it suddenly broke, tho...

Comment: tried datatype as xml as well - jquery is pretty intelligent when it comes to ajax though and it should still get a response with or with out datatype specified - especially since proxy.php is actually the same file and it gets the response. I'm starting to think it's something in word press config not allowing access - cached the old IP or something strange. ps- i hate wordpress.

Comment: Code looks fine - should be no cross-domain issues. Use Fiddler (or any other Http watcher) to see what request are actually send/received so farther suggestions can be made.

Comment: Is it possible that the /blog url does a redirect of some kind? Check the Response in firebug ;-)

Comment: could you also check protocols?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking some of these for more details.  Definitely use Firebug or Chrome's XHR debugger (F12)

> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will
>   expose the following properties and methods:
>
> - readyState
> - status
> - statusText
> - responseXML and/or responseText when the
>     underlying request responded with xml and/or text, respectively
> - setRequestHeader(name, value)
> - getAllResponseHeaders()
> - getResponseHeader()
> - abort()